# Including an existing app as a fragment in a my own app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I was thinking of doing an app with something like 3 frames in which 1 would be a fragment:

- My activity frame would display information related to its purpose
- There would be a frame that would display a menu to choose whatever you want to display in the fragment frame
- The fragment frame would display SMS list, music player widget or app, maps navigation...

The thing is I think that if I want to do so, I have to develop my own fragments for each purpose (SMS, maps, music...). Am I wrong?

Or is there a list of standard Android apps that extends fragments and would be able to fit in my frame?

What led me to that conclusion is the lack of information on that subject and also those topics :

[Self music player fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308905/showing-a-common-music-player-in-all-activities)

[Maps and fragment](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b705bbd72d28d000?pli=1)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The thing is I think that if I want to do so, I have to develop my own fragments for each purpose (SMS, maps, music...). Am I wrong?

You are correct.

> Or is there a list of standard Android apps that extends fragments and would be able to fit in my frame?

You cannot generally embed the UI of another application in yours, outside of `RemoteViews` (the technology used for home screen app widgets, etc.).