# play music in all activities

Tags: android, android-activity, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm trying to play music in all activities in my app but when I switch between `mainactivity` and another activity music stopped please someone help me without using **Service**

MainAcivity :

```
ToggleButton MusicButton;
   MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.vaporv2);
        if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

   //code

 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(mediaPlayer!=null && !mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            if(MusicButton.isChecked()){
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
            else
                mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }
```

I don't know what I can do in the other activity.

Comment: Post your logs where it is not working

Comment: @Zoffa i don't know what i should i do in the other activity to keep music playing in it

Comment: Can you explain why would you not prefer extending `Service` class for this task? A generic music player handles the __play music in all activities__ using `Service` running on the background.

Comment: @SuryaTejaKarra cuz i don't want to play music in the background i want just keep music play in all activities in my app , if Service solve my problem i will use it

Comment: @SafaeQueroane I still do not understand what you meant by that.
From what I gather, you'd like to show a **music player panel** in all your activities. I suggest check this link [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308905/showing-a-common-music-player-in-all-activities?rq=1)

Comment: To play music in all activity , try to use MediaPlayer in Application class. But this is not recommended. It will be worst performance.For good performance use MediaPlayer in Service.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain as to why you don't want to use a Service ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the current seek position using extras, but the Music may stop while switching between activities.

I suggest that you use service then in each activity `onPause` event you check if you are switching to another activity in your application or not, if not send some broadcast to the service to stop playing music.